# Even after data retrieval from Table, value is 0

Tags: java, database, sqlite, authentication, jdbc

I have a SQLite database and there is one record with id=2. I am able to login but can't set the id_from_table value(Class variable) value to it's value from table. It is 0 always .Why is this happening? What am I doing wrong here? I can login though ! Help appreciated ,thanks .

database ;
[image]

```
public boolean login(String userid, String userpass) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    String query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? AND passkey = ?";
    try{
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        preparedStatement.setString(1,userid);
        preparedStatement.setString(2,userpass);
        resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        if(resultSet.next()){
            id_from_table = resultSet.getInt("id"); //not working-when retrieved in another class it shows 0
            return true;
        }
        else {
          // System.out.println(resultSet.next());
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    finally {
        preparedStatement.close();
        resultSet.close();
    }
    return false;

}
```

Comment: have you tried `int id_from_table = resultSet ....` ?

Comment: actually when printed in if condition it prints correct value but when retrieved from another class (in my case loginmodel.id_from_table) it is 0 , can't figure out why? It is a global variable

Comment: @minigeek : so the problem is not in this part of the code, please provide a [mcve]  .

Comment: @Berger thanx+sry , I found my solution. Problem was in 3 files + variable wasn't acessible in all classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own way around.

It retrieved value from database but since my variable wasn't `public static` I couldn't access without creating a object (First I did after creating object). And Class I was using for accessing was `LoginModel` but it was supposed to be `Controller` in which my login method was written.

So `Controller.id_from_table` worked. I defined *id_from_table* in Controller and assigned value before `login(username,passkey)` method ends.